# Return wrong date at split time range into array of weeks

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem with function to split my time range into array of weeks. After run for example a time range: `10-08-2020` and `10-09-2020`, my last date is `13-09-2020` instead of `10-09-2020` :/

can someone tell me what is wrong with my function?

```
async getArrayOfWeeks(start: string, end: string) {
        const weeks = [];
        let current = new Date(start);
        const end = new Date(end);

        const increaseDays = (date: Date, amount: number) => new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + amount));

        while(current < end) {
            const beginOfWeek = new Date(current);
            let endOfWeek = increaseDays(current, 6);

            endOfWeek = endOfWeek > end ? end : endOfWeek;

            weeks.push({
                'week': beginOfWeek + " " + endOfWeek;
            });

            current = increaseDays(current, 1);
        }

        return weeks; 
    }
```

thanks for nay help :)

Comment: you shouldn't reinitialize `end` - it's both an argument and a `const`. Also, I assume `dto.to` is supposed to be `end` on line 4?

Comment: @CharlieG, yes, i correct in main post

Answer (score 1):

I believe `endOfWeek = endOfWeek > start ? end : endOfWeek;` should probably be checking against `end` and not `start`, since every date you produce is only adding more and more to `start` and you want to check to see if you've gone past `end`

Answer (score 0):

In this line here

```
endOfWeek = endOfWeek > start ? end : endOfWeek;
```

you are checking if the endOfWeek is over start, and what you should be checking if it is over end, so if it is then just say, okay end of the week is on the end date as the one given above is past it (eliminates the possibility of getting the 13th of October if the end date is 10th of October)

Now there is also  a Date function called 'setDate' which does what you have done with increaseDays, although it might look prettier it is a waste not to use a built in function. So instead of this:

```
const increaseDays = (date: Date, amount: number) => new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + amount));
let endOfWeek = increaseDays(current, 6);
```

you could simply do

```
let endOfWeek = current.setDate(current.getDate() + 6);
```

EDIT:
Your date formats are off, they need to be in a ISO 'YYYY-MM-DD' format by default. If you wanna use your format I recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library that is great for working with dates and their formatting

```
function hello() {
  let start = '2020-08-10'
  let end = '2020-09-10'
  const weeks = [];
  let current = new Date(start);
  console.log(current)
  end = new Date(end);

  while(current < end) {
    const beginOfWeek = new Date(current);
    let endOfWeek = current.setDate(beginOfWeek.getDate() + 6);

    endOfWeek = endOfWeek > end ? end : endOfWeek;

    weeks.push({
      'week': beginOfWeek + " " + endOfWeek
    });
    current.setDate(current.getDate() + 7);
  }
  console.log(weeks)
  return weeks; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed version of your code above. However it doesn't account for the correct starting day in the week but since that wasn't the question I'll leave it as it is.

```
const getArrayOfWeeks = (start: string, end: string) => {
    const weeks = [];
    let current = new Date(start);
    let endDate = new Date(end); //const end = new Date(dto.to);

    while(current < endDate) {
        const beginOfWeek = new Date(current);
        let endOfWeek = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate() + 6));  //let endOfWeek = increaseDays(current, 6);

        endOfWeek = endOfWeek > endDate ? endDate : endOfWeek;  //endOfWeek = endOfWeek > start ? end : endOfWeek;

        weeks.push({
            'week': beginOfWeek + " " + endOfWeek  //'week': beginOfWeek + " " + endOfWeek;  notice the removed ";"
        });

        current = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1)); //current = increaseDays(current, 1);
    }

    return weeks; 
}

console.log(getArrayOfWeeks('10-08-2020','10-09-2020'));
```

Will return

```
[
  {
    week: 'Thu Oct 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00) Fri Oct 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)'
  }
]
```